# Can't start MySQL in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

An hour ago I installed MySQL community edition . I dont know if its related to it . I also have MAMP installed on my pc but I closed it so I dont think port 3306 is occupied .
Here is the log of XAMPP MySQL error

```
   2018-10-26 23:53:31 160c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x231f)

2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-10-26 23:53:31 5644 [ERROR] Aborting
```

and here is the config file , please check if there is wrong setting I have done . Thank you all in advance

```
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/Xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/Xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/Xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/Xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/Xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from the old days when I used mysql on windows: my.cnf was stored in windows folder those days, and maybe the new installer recognized the already existing my.cnf? I would uninstall the latest install...check if the existing solution is working again. Then, I would search for my.cnf, and if it was in a system folder, I would rename it before installing the community edition again. Your error descriptions sounds like the new installed database environment cannot access old style tables or something like that. Again, just a quick guess...

Comment: So should I re install xampp or sql community edition ?

Comment: I would uninstall the latest installed package first and then try to find if the package that was exisiting earlier is still working